# Ant Design Angular - Upload - nzCustomRequest no sending image data with the request

Tags: angular, antd

I have been trying to get `nzCustomRequest` to work, so that I can upload image file with my API that requires some additional info other than image data itself (the reason because of which I cannot use `nzAction`). No matter how I try, the image data is never getting forwarded to `POST` request.

HTML:

```
<nz-upload
  [nzCustomRequest]="handleUpload"
  nzListType="picture-card"
  [(nzFileList)]="fileList"
  [nzShowButton]="fileList.length < 3"
  [nzPreview]="handlePreview">
    <i class="anticon anticon-plus"></i>
    <div class="ant-upload-text">Upload</div>
</nz-upload>
```

Component function:

```
handleUpload = (item: any) => {
  console.log('uploading image...');
  console.log(item);

  this.http.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/', {item})
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));

  }
}
```

Request Payload:

```
{"name":"file","file":{"uid":"srqapwtdma"},"withCredentials":false}
```

As you can see above, there is no image data inluded in this request body.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-setup-mx855y?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

[Upload Documentation](https://ng.ant.design/components/upload/en#api)

Please help me figure out how I can include image data in my 'POST' request using `nzCustomRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Docs](https://ng.ant.design/components/upload/en):

```
handleUpload = (item: any) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(item.name, item.file as any);
    this.http.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/', formData).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log("success", res.id);
        item.onSuccess(item.file);
      },
      (err) => {
        item.onError(err, item.file);
      }
    );
  } 
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-setup-3gkfrs)